# Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't resolve my problem, this is the error from mysql that I'm getting:

[image: Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']

I can edit and update my data when I've got one record in the database but when I add two rows, I get the error.

Some pictures from database

And when I change the row, row ID goes down to 0 and that's is a problem as I can't edit other rows.

[image: When i try to change row, first row ID goes down to 0]
[image: Database]

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `dati` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `value2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1
```

Update Code:

```
<?php // Izlabot datus datubāzē!
$titletxt = $_POST['title_edit'];
$value1 = $_POST['value1_edit'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2_edit'];

if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Neizdevās savienoties ar MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="UPDATE dati SET ID='$ID',title= '$titletxt',value1='$value1',value2='$value2' WHERE 1";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo '<script>
        alert(" Ieraksts ir veiksmīgi labots! ");

        window.location.href = "index.php";
    </script>';
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

From form:

```
<?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
              echo "Neizdevās savienoties ar MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dati");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td><input id='titled' type='text' name='title_edit' value='" . $row['title'] . "'></td>";
                  echo "<td><input id='value1d' type='text' name='value1_edit' value='" . $row['value1'] . "'></td>";
                  echo "<td><input id='value2d' type='text' name='value2_edit' value='" . $row['value2'] . "'></td>";
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>";
                  echo "<td><button name='edit' id='edit_btn' class='frm_btns' value='" . $row['ID'] . "'>Edit</button></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

It couldn't read the value of ID, as 0 was returned.

Comment: do not enter anything for the ID.

Comment: im not enter anything for ID

Comment: Do you thing that schema?

Comment: http://www.bildites.lv/images/jvacde0uqy7dahton1w2.jpg Photo of schema

Comment: If you edit in phpMyAdmin it could be a bug there, which version do you use?

Comment: Version information: 3.5.1

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE dati; run this query post the results in the main post.That is the schema.

Comment: What is the updating code?

Comment: Oh, okey, i add in post.

Comment: you have `ID='$ID'`, but `$ID` is not set to anything, so this becomes `ID=''` which would result in `ID=0`.

Comment: Also,is there a need for auto increment to be 3?If not use ALTER TABLE doti AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; to increment with 1.

Comment: @Mihai well that's the next value to insert. Because the largest `ID` is `2` (from the screenshots) the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is currently `3`.

Comment: @t.niese No it means it will autoincrement from 3 to 3, so its 2 the next will be 5 and so on.

Comment: @Mihai No, it doesn't. It means the next row inserted will get `ID=3`.

Comment: @ypercube Can you set it at table creation,in the sense I mean?I thought that was it.

Comment: That is controlled by [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) which is a server wide variable (it affects all tables in all databases in the server)

Comment: @t.niese You were right,oops.

Answer (score 54):

For those arriving at this question because of the question title (as I did), this solved my problem:

This error can indicate that the table's PRIMARY KEY is not set to AUTO-INCREMENT, *(and your insert query did not specify an ID value).*

To resolve:

Check that there is a PRIMARY KEY set on your table, **and** that the PRIMARY KEY is set to AUTO-INCREMENT.

[How to add auto-increment to column in mysql database using phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434801/how-to-add-auto-increment-to-column-in-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin/33686718#33686718)

Comment: Also make sure you're on the `right` database. I need coffee. #lame

Comment: And you need to remove any row that might have gotten added with an ID of 0 because auto incrementing starts at 1 and it'll try to fix that 0 and make it a 1, but chances are there already is an ID of 1 so you'll see an error about duplicate reindexing.

Answer (score 6):

The error log like (In my case), I'm using ***Aurora*** DB:

> PHP message: WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `date173_postmeta

How to fix it using ***MySQL Workbench***:

1- Connect at your DB, and go to the table with the issue, in my case `date173_postmeta`

2- Select the tools icon:

[image]

3- In the windows/tab at right, ***select the AI checkbox*** and ***click on Apply button***:

[image]

Following the last steps my issues gone.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your code attempts to change every row in the data changing the primary key to the value in $ID. This is not set anywhere in your code, and presumably is being cast as 0

```
$sql="UPDATE `dati` SET `ID`='$ID',`title`= 
'$titletxt',`value1`='$value1',`value2`='$value2' WHERE 1";
```

The primary key value should be sent to the form and returned so it can be processed by your code, but the value should be retained, hence....

```
$sql="UPDATE `dati` SET `title`= 
'$titletxt',`value1`='$value1',`value2`='$value2' WHERE `ID`=$ID";
```

You should also read up on MySQL injection - even after you've fixed the errors here, anyone can do just about anything they want with your database.

Answer (score 4):

```
ID int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT(1,3)
```

This will set the ID attribute to auto increment its value for every new row inserted in the table, thus preventing duplicate keys.

Comment: mh, correct, problem is for $ID, they give the same numbers :/

Comment: $sql="UPDATE `dati` SET `title`= '$titletxt',`value1`='$value1',`value2`='$value2' WHERE `ID`='$ID'";  With this he do nothing, all compile but information wont change.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - what **exactly** should be tried, and why should that solve the problem? Keep in mind that such an explanation helps others to understand your answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem in `set ID = $ID`

Try removing it so the code should be

```
$sql="UPDATE `dati` `title`=        '$titletxt',`value1`='$value1',`value2`='$value2' WHERE 1";
```

Be sure to change this where cause it'll update ever row with these values

Comment: when i add this $sql="UPDATE `dati` `title`=        '$titletxt',`value1`='$value1',`value2`='$value2' WHERE 1";  they change all rows not single, like a copy.

Comment: @ArvisAvens that what your query in the code currently does. You just have a  `WHERE 1` so you don't limit the update to a row.

Comment: @t.niese i need to add LIMIT 1?

Comment: @ArvisAvens make it `where ID=$ID` but make sure the id was sent correctly in the post aka `$ID=$_POST['ID']`

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that your primery keys are also A-I.

Answer (score 2):

I'd been struggling to fix this. My tables had auto increment (AI) switched on
Before I started tinkering with records I tried a simple repair in phpMyAdmin.
Go to the SQL tab and run each command in turn.

REPAIR TABLE wp_options
REPAIR TABLE wp_users
REPAIR TABLE wp_usermeta

This did the trick for me and allowed me to login.

Answer (score 1):

i am using phpmyadmin,
so go to db , search for wp_postmeta tabel
add AI(auto-increment) to meta_id
save the changes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for me it's because when exporting the db, somehow the order of the column is messed up (eg. `INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES(value1,value2)` becomes `INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES(value2,value1)`)

I have to specify --complete-insert option which ensures that the exported SQL statements include column names explicitly