# why I cant post the data from my html-page

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, database

I use node.js with mysql workbench

my Error I get  when I post the data to Mysql

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

my code node.js am try fixed a lot but I cant always I get error

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "new_schema",
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM new_schema.new_table",
  function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) console.log("The solution is: ", rows);
    else console.log("Error while performing Query.");
  }
);
app.post("/myaction", function (request, response, next) {
  var email = request.body.email;
  var pass = request.body.pass;
  var query = `INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table (email,pass) VALUES ("${email}","${pass}")`;
  connection.query(query, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      response.redirect("/home");
    }
  });
});
```

my Html code here I do  the same of a lot of videos in youtube

```
                <h2 class="email">Please sign up</h2>
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Your Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
                <label for="pass" class="sr-only">New Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="">
                
                <button id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
              </form>
```

Comment: Looks like you miss the `auto_increment` on the `id` column in the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688694/error-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in your question itself. You are asking why you can't POST data from the HTML page. Because there are not any POST methods of any form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/myaction">
  <h2 class="email">Please sign up</h2>
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Your Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="pass" class="sr-only">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="">     
    <button id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Now, you are `post`ing data to `/myaction` route.